# if else conditional statments in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i have a simple app with a single value, 2 buttons and 3 divs.
The value variable starts at 0, the buttons either increases or decrease the value,
i have 3 divs; small, medium & large. i need to render a div based on the value.
if the value is 20, the large div, value less than or equal to 10, medium div, if less than 10, small div.

My goal here is to render a view based on an input from the user.

Here is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const ShowHide = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const [lrg, setLrg] = useState(false);
  const [mid, setMid] = useState(false);
  const [sml, setSml] = useState(true);
 
  
  if (value >= 20 ) {
    setLrg(true) 
    setMid(false) 
    setSml(false)
  }

  if ( value >= 10  && value <= 20) {
    setLrg(false) 
    setMid(true) 
    setSml(false)
  }

  if (value < 10 ) {
    setLrg(false) 
    setMid(false) 
    setSml(true)
  }

  return <>

  <h3>show/hide div</h3>
  <div>
    <h3> value is  :{value}</h3>
    <button className='btn' onClick={() => {setValue(value + 5)}}> add </button>
    <br></br>
    <button className='btn' onClick={() => {setValue(value - 5)}}> minus </button>
  </div>
  <br></br>
  <div className="form"> 
    {lrg && <Lrg />}
    {mid && <Mid />}
    {sml && <Sml />}
  </div>
  </>;
};

 

const Lrg = () => {
  return (
      <div>
    <h3> value is larger than 20</h3>
  </div>
  );
}

const Mid = () => {
  return (
      <div>
    <h3> value is btwn 10 and 20</h3>
  </div>
  );
}

const Sml = () => {
  return (
      <div>
    <h3> value is less than 10</h3>
  </div>
  );
}
export default ShowHide;
```

To make it work, i have defined 3 other variables, sml, med, lrg. that start at false for lrg and med since the value starts at 0, and true for sml since value is 0.
when the values change, i want to update these var accordingly.
however i get this error

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

It comes after i add the if else statements, how do i create some conditions without that error

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of all your `useState`s except for `[value, setValue]`.  Then in your JSX:

```
    {value >= 20 && <Lrg />}
    {value < 20 && value >= 10 && <Mid />}
    {value < 10 && <Sml />}
```

Comment: How about a single statement with ternary operators `{ value >= 20 ? <Lrg /> : value < 10 ? <Sml /> : <Mid /> }`

Comment: While that does work, I play by eslint rules which forbid nested ternaries.  https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-nested-ternary

Comment: Oh I see. That's a shame, tho. I often use this to shorthand if-else statements. I figure `{ value >= 20 && <Lrg /> || value < 10 && <Sml /> || <Mid /> }` wouldn't be perceived much better :-) Your answer is very straight forward, but I don't like it's missing elses, leading to both unnecessary comparisons and more "manual integrity load" for the coder.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use state for checking value range.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ShowHide = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const isSml = value < 10;
  const isMid = value >= 10 && value <= 20;
  const isLrg = value > 20;

  return (
    <>
      <h3>show/hide div</h3>
      <div>
        <h3> value is :{value}</h3>
        <button
          className="btn"
          onClick={() => {
            setValue(value + 5);
          }}
        >
          {' '}
          add{' '}
        </button>
        <br></br>
        <button
          className="btn"
          onClick={() => {
            setValue(value - 5);
          }}
        >
          {' '}
          minus{' '}
        </button>
      </div>
      <br></br>
      <div className="form">
        {isLrg && <Lrg />}
        {isMid && <Mid />}
        {isSml && <Sml />}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const Lrg = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3> value is larger than 20</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

const Mid = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3> value is btwn 10 and 20</h3>
    </div>
  );
};

const Sml = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3> value is less than 10</h3>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ShowHide;
```

Answer (score 0):

i played with it, untill i got some other version

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    
     
    const ShowHide = () => {
      const [value, setValue] = useState(0); 
    
      return <> 
      <h3>show/hide</h3>
      <div>
        <h3> value is  :{value}</h3>
        <button className='btn' onClick={() => {setValue(value + 5)}}> add </button>
     
        <button className='btn' onClick={() => {setValue(value - 5)}}> minus </button>
      </div>
      <br></br>
      <div className="form"> 
        <Answr num={value}/>
      </div>
       
      </>;
    };
    
     
     
     
    
    const Answr = ({num }) =>{
      if (num >= 20){ 
      return (
        <div> 
        <h3> value is greater than 20</h3>
        </div>
        );
     }
      else if (num >= 10 && num < 20 ) {
         return (
          <div> 
           <h3> value is between 10 and 20</h3>
          </div>
        );
     } else {
            return (
          <div> 
           <h3> value is less than 10 </h3>
          </div>
        );
     }
    };
    export default ShowHide;
```